# Power BI: Calculating temperature bandwidth "thickness" within one temperature parameter

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

Considering that my temperature (T01 - Green) bandwidth range should not exceed 40°C, but it does exceed in some instances, is there a way to calculate difference assuming that T=100°C is max. limit where temperature could go and T=60°C is minimum limit. Everything above or below those ranges is a "warning low temperature or high temperature"?

Data what I am using is on Picture 2, it is like 1 minute interval, many points in question.

Pity that PBI doesnt have like some chart or axis line where you can actually calculate how big is your bandwidth like on the chart below.

[image: Pic 1 - Temperature]

[image: Pic 2 - Data]

```
T100 + = CALCULATE(MAX(CS170113[T01 [°C]]]),FILTER(ALL(CS170113[T01 [°C]]]),CS170113[T01 [°C]]]>=100))
```

I did this measure, but it is overlapping my T01 as you can maybe notice, is there a way to make this measure T100+ so that I can see only values >=100 without overlapping with temporary T01?
[image: Pic 3 - T01]

Comment: You want to replace temps over 100 and under 60 with warning text? Or you want to show a constant line that goes on 100 &60?

Comment: Not really, constant lines are fine but I would like to know that exact difference from for example over 100 degrees and how much is below 100 and if it is exceeding assumed 40 degrees. I need calculation.

Comment: Don't really understand, is a line that counts rows when temp>100 ok? Then it would be a measure like 
Over_100 = CALCULATE(COUNTROWS(Fact),FILTER(Fact,Fact[TO1C]>100)
and similarly for 40 degrees? It would show how many minutes had temp over limits for each Mhz?

Comment: Hmm not that, I tried just to see what I will get but not a straight line definetly, but maybe similar to my values on chart but with those values over 100?

Comment: YEah, it won't be a straight line, it would count how many rows where over 100 temp. For a straight line, you should press the graph, under visualizations, there is Analytics button, where you can add constant line

Comment: Thats what I am saying...I dont need straight line, is there a way to calculate to similar to this: SWITCH(TRUE(),AND(CS170145[P0 [mbar]]]>20,CS170145[P1 [mbar]]]>20),"Hi",AND(CS170145[P0 [mbar]]]<=20,CS170145[P1 [mbar]]]<=20),"Lo","Alt")

Comment: @karlisssl Check it out updated picture + measure that I made..